# iOS Audio Unit - Creating Stereo Sine Waves

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

Over the weekend I hit a stumbling block learning how to program audio synthesis on iOS. I have been developing on iOS for several years, but I am just getting into the audio synthesis aspect.  Right now, I am just programming demo apps to help me learn the concepts.  I have currently been able to build and stack sine waves in a playback renderer for Audio Units without a problem.  But, I want to understand what is going on in the renderer so I can render 2 separate sine waves in each Left and Right Channel.  Currently, I assume that in my init audio section I would need to make the following changes:

From:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate = kSampleRate;
    audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
```

To:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate = kSampleRate;
    audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
```

But, the renderer is somewhat greek to me.  I have been working off of any tutorial or sample code I can find.  I can make things work for the given context of a mono signal, but I cannot make the renderer generate stereo signals. All I want is one distinct frequency in a left channel and a different frequency in a right channel - but I honestly don't understand the renderer enough to get it working.  I have attempted the memcpy function into mBuffers[0] and mbuffers[1], but that crashes the app. My render is below (it currently contains stacked sine waves, but for the stereo example I can just use one wave of a set frequency in each channel though).

```
#define kOutputBus 0
#define kSampleRate 44100
//44100.0f
#define kWaveform (M_PI * 2.0f / kSampleRate)

OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon,
                          AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                          const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                          UInt32 inBusNumber,
                          UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                          AudioBufferList *ioData) {

        HomeViewController *me = (HomeViewController *)inRefCon;

    static int phase = 1;
    static int phase1 = 1;

    for(UInt32 i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; i++) {

        int samples = ioData->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize / sizeof(SInt16);

        SInt16 values[samples];

        float waves;
        float volume=.5;
        float wave1;

        for(int j = 0; j < samples; j++) {


            waves = 0;
            wave1 = 0;

            MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];


            wave1 = sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr1 * phase1)*sharedManager.globalVol1;
            if (0.000001f > wave1) {
                [me setFr1:sharedManager.globalFr1];
                phase1 = 0;
                //NSLog(@"switch");
            }

            waves += wave1;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr2 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol2;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr3 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol3;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr4 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol4;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr5 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol5;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr6 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol6;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr7 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol7;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr8 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol8;
            waves += sin(kWaveform * sharedManager.globalFr9 * phase)*sharedManager.globalVol9;
            waves *= 32767 / 9; // <--------- make sure to divide by how many waves you're stacking

            values[j] = (SInt16)waves;
            values[j] += values[j]<<16;

            phase++;
            phase1++;

        }

        memcpy(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData, values, samples * sizeof(SInt16));

    }


    return noErr;

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If the format is interleaved (as your ASBD suggests), then the samples will be in one buffer alternating left and right: `LRLRLRLR`.  However, it would be unusual to have an interleaved format in a callback- typically the format is the canonical format for the OS.

Comment: Thanks. I actually just figured it all out just a few minutes ago. It is interleaved as you said, though. I had to figure out how to loop through the callback to render the sine waves in distinct L&R channels. Thanks for the help though!!

Comment: Hello jwkerr, I was hoping that I could talk you into posting your rendering function. I've been trying to get stereo rendering working for a while and can't quite get it. Thanks

Comment: Hello @jwkerr.Can u tell me how to set the AudioStreamBasicDescription? I want to get the stereo sine waves too!

Answer (score 3):

The OP seems to have solved his problem, but I thought posting an explicit answer would be helpful to the rest of us.

I had the same question of wanting to direct the tones to left and right channels independently. It's easiest to describe in terms of Matt Gallagher's now-standard [An iOS tone generator (an introduction to AudioUnits)](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html).

The first change to make is to set (following @jwkerr) `streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;` (instead of `streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;`) in the `createToneUnit` method. Once that is done and you have two channels/buffers in each frame, you need to fill the left and right buffers independently in `RenderTone()`:

```
// Set the left and right buffers independently
Float32 tmp;
Float32 *buffer0 = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
Float32 *buffer1 = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

// Generate the samples
for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inNumberFrames; frame++) {
    tmp = sin(theta) * amplitude;

    if (channelLR[0]) buffer0[frame] = tmp; else buffer0[frame] = 0;
    if (channelLR[1]) buffer1[frame] = tmp; else buffer1[frame] = 0;

    theta += theta_increment;
    if (theta > 2.0 * M_PI) theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;
}
```

Of course `channelLR[2]` is a `bool` array whose elements you set to indicate whether the respective channel is audible. Notice that the program needs to explicitly set the frames of silent channels to zero, otherwise you get some funny tones out.

Comment: channelLR needs explaining more.

Comment: Edited. Is that helpful?

Comment: when do you set channelLR? I've tried your example but it's static

Comment: You are using this code in a C function (as in the example), correct? There are many options for setting `channelLR[]`. You can make it a global, you can pass it through `inRefCon`, or you could set it within the callback itself. You only need to set it before you start running the callback.

Comment: Yes, in C. sounds like you are saying you only set this once. so not sure why it is even there. thanks for editing though. still not sure how your solution works.