# iOS using AudioQueueNewOutput to output sound in both left and right channel

Tags: ios, audioqueue

I am developing an app to show sin wave.
I am using AudioQueueNewOutput to output mono sound is OK, but when I come to stereo output, I have no idea how to do it.
I know the `mChannelsPerFrame = 2` can generate wave in both left and right channel.

I also want to know what is the sequence of sending bytes to left and right channel? Is the first byte to left channel and the second byte to right channel?

Code:

```
_audioFormat = new AudioStreamBasicDescription();

_audioFormat->mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;    // 44100
_audioFormat->mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
_audioFormat->mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
_audioFormat->mFramesPerPacket = 1;
_audioFormat->mChannelsPerFrame = NUM_CHANNELS;     // 1
_audioFormat->mBitsPerChannel = BITS_PER_CHANNEL;   // 16
_audioFormat->mBytesPerPacket = BYTES_PER_FRAME;    // 2 
_audioFormat->mBytesPerFrame = BYTES_PER_FRAME;     // 2
```

and

```
_sineTableLength = _audioFormat.mSampleRate / SAMPLE_LIMIT_FACTOR; // 44100/100 = 441
_sineTable = new SInt16[_sineTableLength];
for(int i = 0; i < _sineTableLength; i++)
    {
        // Transfer values between -1.0 and 1.0 to integer values between -sample max and sample max

        _sineTable[i] = (SInt16)(sin(i * 2 * M_PI / _sineTableLength) * 32767);
    }
```

and

```
AudioQueueNewOutput (&_audioFormat,
                     playbackCallback,
                     (__bridge void *)(self),
                     nil,
                     nil,
                     0,
                     &_queueObject);

static void playbackCallback (void* inUserData,
                          AudioQueueRef inAudioQueue,
                          AudioQueueBufferRef   bufferReference){
  SInt16* sample = (SInt16*)bufferReference->mAudioData;
  // bufferSize 1024
  for(int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i += _audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame, sample++)
  {
  // set value for *sample
  // 9ms sin wave and 4.5ms 0
  ...
  }
  ...
  AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(...)
}
```

Comment: I just see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353033/ios-audio-unit-creating-stereo-sine-waves?rq=1 , I need to use AudioUnitSetProperty?

Answer (score 0):

Several days later,I have found the answer.

First: `AudioStreamBasicDescription` can set just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31455268/edit/9a3d5fe6-415f-4067-96aa-17c82b5a77b5) ;

Then: `bufferSize` change from `1024` to `2048` ;

And: `SInt16` in `SInt16* sample = (SInt16*)bufferReference->mAudioData;` all change to `SInt32`. Because the channel double,the bits double;

Last: Each 16 bits contains data that left or right channel need in `sample`,just feed it whatever you want.